# PDFlib - change origin of text to top-left from default of bottom-left

Tags: pdflib

In `pdflib`:

```php
$font = $p->load_font("Helvetica", "unicode", "");
$p->setfont($font, 12);
$p->set_text_pos(100, 100);
$p->show('My text');
```

First arguments of `set_text_pos($x, $y)` tells library where to position bottom-left corner of text element.

**Question**. How can I change the origin of text to be top-left corner, so that "My text" string appears *below* 100x100 coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the more comfortable `fit_textline()` call. In this case, you can replace your four lines with a single line:

```
$p->fit_textline('My text', 100, 100, 'fontname=Helvetica encoding=unicode fontsize=12 position {top left} ');
```